# The identifier that starts with (query) Maximum length is 128

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Problem:** I am using a sp on sql server where I took parameter which modify the query and then run the full query in the server. While I am passing that parameter to sp then it says: "The identifier that starts with 'WHERE d.LastModified<1676270281779 AND (p.ProductName LIKE '%2004%' OR p.ProductBarcode LIKE '%2004%') AND d.SupplierId='SUP-001' is too long. Maximum length is 128."

**THE QUERY:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_SupComProducts] @whereClause NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(max)
        , @status VARCHAR(25);

    SET @status = 'IN'
    SET @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT
        p.ProductId,
        p.CompanyId,
        p.ProductName,
        p.ProductGrossWeight,
        p.ProductNetWeight,
        p.ProductUnit,
        p.CategoryId,
        p.BrandId,
        p.ProductBarcode,
        p.MinShelfLife,
        p.ProductMargin,
        p.IsWeighted,
        p.PVAT,
        p.ProductMargin,
        p.AFSProduct,
        ISNULL(sp.ProductBarcode, 0) AS Barcode,
        ISNULL(sp.CostPrice, 0) AS CostPrice,
        ISNULL(sp.TradePrice, 0) AS TradePrice,
        ISNULL(sp.MRP, 0) AS MRP,
        ISNULL(sp.SellingPrice, 0) AS SellingPrice,
        ISNULL(sp.VAT, 0) AS VAT,
        ISNULL((
            SELECT SUM(ProductQty) AS ProductQty
            FROM StockDetails
            WHERE ProductId = p.ProductId AND [Status]= ''' + @status + '''' + 
        '),0) AS CurrentStock
 FROM Supplier d
     JOIN Product p
         ON p.CompanyId = d.CompanyId
     LEFT JOIN StockDetails sd
         ON sd.ProductId = p.ProductId
     LEFT JOIN SupplierProduct sp
         ON sp.ProductId = p.ProductId ' + @whereClause

    EXEC (@query)
END
GO
```

Please if there are any resolve you guys know already, it will be much appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**SP EXEC:**

```
EXEC [dbo].[get_SupComProducts] @whereClause="WHERE d.LastModified<1676270281779 AND (p.ProductName LIKE '%2004%' OR p.ProductBarcode LIKE '%2004%') AND d.SupplierId='SUP-00123'"
```

**If I remove any of the AND query then it works, but the full query says the error.**

Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
The identifier that starts with 'WHERE d.LastModified<1676270281779 AND (p.ProductName LIKE '%2004%' OR p.ProductBarcode LIKE '%2004%') AND d.SupplierId='SUP-001' is too long. Maximum length is 128.

Comment: You cannot use double quotes for strings in SQL server. Use single quotes and double-up any embedded quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there might be issues with your procedure, this particular one comes from the way you call it. Double quotes in SQL, by default, designate object names, and in MS SQL Server, maximum length for any object name is 128 characters. That's where you are getting this error, I suspect.

So, in your sp call, you need to replace your double quotes with single ones, and appropriately escape all single quotes inside it. Something like this:

```sql
EXEC [dbo].[get_SupComProducts] @whereClause = '
WHERE
d.LastModified<1676270281779 AND (
p.ProductName LIKE ''%2004%''
OR p.ProductBarcode LIKE ''%2004%''
) AND d.SupplierId=''SUP-00123''
';
```